# Upload two versions of an image (compressed and uncompressed) using CarrierWave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave and S3 to store images uploaded by the user in my rails app.

I want to store 2 versions of the image - one is the original, uncompressed image and the other is its compressed version. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to your uploader:

```
version :name_of_your_version do
  process resize_to_fit: [200,200]
end
```

Inside the block you can pass whatever processes you want and these will be executed and saved on a version called `name_of_your_version`.

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the URL of this version's image?

Comment: record.mounted_column.name_of_version.url

Comment: Thanks. This works too: record.mounted_column.url(:name_of_version)